Borsch deserialize error
when building i got this error:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `initialize_game::InitializeGameBumps: BorshSerialize` is not satisfied
  --> programs/stake-deck/src/lib.rs:14:1
   |
14 | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `BorshSerialize` is not implemented for `initialize_game::InitializeGameBumps`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `BorshSerialize`:
             bool
             isize
             i8
             i16
             i32
             i64
             i128
             usize
           and 113 others
   = help: see issue #48214
   = help: add `#![feature(trivial_bounds)]` to the crate attributes to enable
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `initialize_game::InitializeGameBumps: BorshDeserialize` is not satisfied
  --> programs/stake-deck/src/lib.rs:14:1
   |
14 | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `BorshDeserialize` is not implemented for `initialize_game::InitializeGameBumps`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `BorshDeserialize`:
             bool
             isize
             i8
             i16
             i32
             i64
             i128
             usize
           and 86 others
   = help: see issue #48214
   = help: add `#![feature(trivial_bounds)]` to the crate attributes to enable
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `initialize_game::InitializeGameBumps: BorshSerialize` is not satisfied
  --> programs/stake-deck/src/lib.rs:22:12
   |
22 |     pub fn initialize_game(ctx: Context<InitializeGame>, bumps: InitializeGameBumps, min_bet: u64, max_players: u8, fee_percentage: u8, payout_percentage: u8, admin: Pubk...
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `BorshSerialize` is not implemented for `initialize_game::InitializeGameBumps`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `BorshSerialize`:
             bool
             isize
             i8
             i16
             i32
             i64
             i128
             usize
           and 113 others
note: required for `instruction::InitializeGame` to implement `BorshSerialize`
  --> programs/stake-deck/src/lib.rs:14:1
   |
14 | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced in this `derive` macro
...
22 |     pub fn initialize_game(ctx: Context<InitializeGame>, bumps: InitializeGameBumps, min_bet: u64, max_players: u8, fee_percentage: u8, payout_percentage: u8, admin: Pubk...
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `InstructionData`
  --> src/lib.rs:279:1
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `AnchorSerialize` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
warning: `stake-deck` (lib) generated 3 warnings

here's my initialize code:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use crate::{error::StakeDeckError, state::{GameState, PlayersAccount}, GameAccount, Player,  VaultState};

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeGame<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub first_player: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = first_player,
        seeds = [b"player", first_player.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        space = GameAccount::INIT_SPACE,
    )]
    pub game_account: Account<'info, GameAccount>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = first_player,
        seeds = [b"state", game_account.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        space = 8 + 32 + 8 + 1 + 1, // Adjust space for owner and balance
    )]
    pub vault_state: Account<'info, VaultState>,
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"vault", vault_state.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub vault: SystemAccount<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

impl<'info> InitializeGame<'info> {
    pub fn initialize_game(
        ctx: Context<InitializeGame>,
        bumps: &InitializeGameBumps,
        min_bet: u64,
        max_players: u8, // Dynamic max players
        fee_percentage: u8,
        payout_percentage: u8,
        admin: Pubkey
    ) -> Result<()> {
            let first_player: &Signer<'_> = &ctx.accounts.first_player;  
            let game_account = &mut ctx.accounts.game_account; 
            // let bump = ctx.bumps.game_account;
            let vault_state = &mut ctx.accounts.vault_state;

        if first_player.key() == Pubkey::default() {
            return Err(StakeDeckError::InvalidPlayerAccount.into());
        }

        let player = Player {
            pubkey: first_player.key(),
            bet_amount: 0, // Initial bet amount is zero
        };

        game_account.players.push(player);
        game_account.min_bet = min_bet;
        game_account.max_players = max_players;
        game_account.fee_percentage = fee_percentage;
        game_account.payout_percentage = payout_percentage;
        game_account.bet_amount = 0;
        game_account.game_state = GameState::WaitingForPlayers; // Initial state
        // game_account.bump =bump;
        // game_account.admin = admin;


        // Vault
        vault_state.owner = first_player.key();
        vault_state.vault_bump = bumps.vault;
        vault_state.state_bump = bumps.vault_state;

        Ok(())
    }
}

lib.rs:
pub mod constants;
pub mod error;
pub mod instructions;
pub mod state;

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

pub use constants::*;
pub use instructions::*;
pub use state::*;

declare_id!("2v5AG8W6Zce7Z6y2cc14GbviaBSNvX3ZWKChCUiKtfdW");

#[program]
pub mod stake_deck {
    use super::*;

    // pub fn initialize_game(ctx: Context<InitializeGame>, min_bet: u64, max_players: u8, fee_percentage: u8, payout_percentage: u8, admin: Pubkey) -> Result<()> 
    // {
    //    // let bumps = c9tx.bumps;  // Clone bumps before borrowing ctx mutably
    //     InitializeGame::initialize_game(ctx, min_bet, max_players, fee_percentage, payout_percentage, admin)
    pub fn initialize_game(ctx: Context<InitializeGame>, bumps: InitializeGameBumps, min_bet: u64, max_players: u8, fee_percentage: u8, payout_percentage: u8, admin: Pubkey) -> Result<()> {
        InitializeGame::initialize_game(ctx, bumps, min_bet, max_players, fee_percentage, payout_percentage, admin)
    }

    pub fn initialize_config(ctx: Context<InitializeConfig>) -> Result<()> {
        InitializeConfig::initialize_config(ctx)
    }

    pub fn start_game(ctx: Context<StartGame>) -> Result<()> {
        StartGame::start_game(ctx)
    }

    pub fn place_bet(ctx: Context<PlaceBet>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        PlaceBet::place_bet(ctx, amount)
    }

    pub fn end_game(ctx: Context<EndGame>) -> Result<()> {
        EndGame::end_game(ctx)
    }
}

This is where the error is showing

pub fn initialize_game(ctx: Context<InitializeGame>, bumps: InitializeGameBumps, min_bet: u64, max_players: u8, fee_percentage: u8, payout_percentage: u8, admin: Pubkey) -> Result<()> {
        InitializeGame::initialize_game(ctx, bumps, min_bet, max_players, fee_percentage, payout_percentage, admin)
    }


What's the Solana version, anchor version and crates are you using in your project

root@DESKTOP-9HIHOP7:/home/prime/solana# solana --version
solana-cli 1.18.24 (src:6b04e881; feat:3241752014, client:Agave)
root@DESKTOP-9HIHOP7:/home/prime/solana# anchor --version
anchor-cli 0.30.1
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.30.1"
solana-program = "1.18.17"

What if, in your lib.rs, you pass the bumps directly as a reference from the context?
Also, since you are implementing functionality to your context, you probably don't need to pass the ctx as an argument.
You can probably do something like this: --- pub fn initialize_game(ctx: Context, min_bet: u64, max_players: u8, fee_percentage: u8, payout_percentage: u8, admin: Pubkey) -> Result<()> {
ctx.accounts.initialize_game(&ctx.bumps, min_bet, max_players, fee_percentage, payout_percentage, admin)
} --- Don't forget to remove the ctx from the method

You don't need to pass the bumps as an argument in your instruction. You can use ctx.bumps.game_account and ctx.bumps.vault_state to access the bumps for both accounts in the instruction.
Your new InitializeGame impl block should look like this:
impl<'info> InitializeGame<'info> {
    pub fn initialize_game(
        ctx: Context<InitializeGame>,
        min_bet: u64,
        max_players: u8, // Dynamic max players
        fee_percentage: u8,
        payout_percentage: u8,
        admin: Pubkey
    ) -> Result<()> {
            let first_player: &Signer<'_> = &ctx.accounts.first_player;  
            let game_account = &mut ctx.accounts.game_account; 
            // let bump = ctx.bumps.game_account;
            let vault_state = &mut ctx.accounts.vault_state;

        if first_player.key() == Pubkey::default() {
            return Err(StakeDeckError::InvalidPlayerAccount.into());
        }

        let player = Player {
            pubkey: first_player.key(),
            bet_amount: 0, // Initial bet amount is zero
        };

        game_account.players.push(player);
        game_account.min_bet = min_bet;
        game_account.max_players = max_players;
        game_account.fee_percentage = fee_percentage;
        game_account.payout_percentage = payout_percentage;
        game_account.bet_amount = 0;
        game_account.game_state = GameState::WaitingForPlayers; // Initial state
        // game_account.bump =bump;
        // game_account.admin = admin;


        // Vault
        vault_state.owner = first_player.key();
        vault_state.vault_bump = ctx.bumps.vault;
        vault_state.state_bump = ctx.bumps.vault_state;

        Ok(())
    }
}

And your new instruction entry point should be:
pub mod stake_deck {
    use super::*;

    ...
    pub fn initialize_game(ctx: Context<InitializeGame>, min_bet: u64, max_players: u8, fee_percentage: u8, payout_percentage: u8, admin: Pubkey) -> Result<()> {
        InitializeGame::initialize_game(ctx, min_bet, max_players, fee_percentage, payout_percentage, admin)
    }
    ...
}


